# Артефакты во время построения проекта на первом агенте переносились на второй агент

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity

У меня есть билд сервер и два билд агента. На одном агенте у меня происходит билд проэкта. На втором агенте происходит deploy. Мне нужно что бы артефакты во время построения проэкта на первом агенте переносились на второй агент. Подскажите приблизительно где эти конфигурации ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё что нужно было это артифакты. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Artifact+Dependencies